# How to check if a Google PubSub subscription got created after its context has been cancelled

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub

During a Google PubSub **CreateSubscription** the context gets cancelled. This results in the **CreateSubcription** function returning the following error: `rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled`

Most of the time the Subscription will still get created, but sometimes (although I have yet to see it happen) it may not, depending on at what point the Context got cancelled.

What I want to do is delete any potential subscription that may have been created.

My current solution is to try and create the Subscription again, with a new Context and PubSub Client. It will either create, or return an error, if the Subscription already exists.

Another solution is to poll to see if the Subscription exists via the PubSub subscription **Exists** function, and if it exists then delete it, or if after a set amount of time it does not exist then assume the subscription never got created.

Both ideas don't seem that good, is there a more idiomatic way of achieving this?